# Find combinations of integers that add to a sum

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a program that takes the statement `X + Y = Sum` and can be queried to output possible values for `X` and `Y` for a given `Sum`. Each of X and Y can be integers in [0, `Sum`]. For example, for `X + Y = 10`, I would like to get (0,10), (1,9), ..., (10, 0).

How can this be done in Prolog?

Comment: This is not a good first Prolog program. Take a textbook, like Sterling & Shapiro to start with.

Comment: Prolog is counter-intuitive if viewed from the perspective of common, imperative programming. Forget what you know about programming and start with a fresh brain. If Prolog was the first language you had learned, the other ones would seem weird. ;) Beginners always have trouble with this because they try to map it to their existing programming patterns. It's a very different pattern. In addition to false's book recommendation, there are some reasonable introductory tutorials, like [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/) for just getting started.

Comment: Once you get the basics of Prolog under your belt, and then read a little on CLPFD (constraint logic programming over finite domains), then finding the solutions to `X+Y=10` will become quite trivial. :) In your original problem statement, by the way, you're missing information about constraints (*e.g.*, what are the domains of `X` and `Y`?).

Comment: They would both be integers >= 0 and <= 10.

Comment: By the way, after you've learned how to think in Prolog, you'll actually find it frustrating how much more tedious it is to do certain things in other non-Prolog languages. :)

Comment: The solution to your specific problem is much more intuitive in Prolog than it is in an imperative language. It's literally almost as simple as stipulating, `X #>= 0, Y #>= 0, X + Y #= 10.`. As false said, CLPFD is not the place to start, though, for a first Prolog program, since you'd be missing a lot of fundamentals.

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to solve this, depending on how you want to define and constrain your problem. A "first attempt" sort of thing would be:

> Which couple of numbers between 0 and 10 are such that the sum is 10?

You need to type the `;` after each solution:

```
?- between(0, 10, X), between(0, 10, Y), plus(X, Y, 10).
X = 0,
Y = 10 ;
X = 1,
Y = 9 ;
X = 2,
Y = 8 ;
X = 3,
Y = 7 ;
X = 4,
Y = 6 ;
X = Y, Y = 5 ;
X = 6,
Y = 4 ;
X = 7,
Y = 3 ;
X = 8,
Y = 2 ;
X = 9,
Y = 1 ;
X = 10,
Y = 0 ;
false.
```

The comments to your question gave you a lot of useful advice as to where to go from here. In itself this solution is not very helpful in understanding or learning Prolog. Neither is (in my personal opinion) the CLPFD solution:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- [X,Y] ins 0..10, X + Y #= 10, label([X,Y]).
X = 0,
Y = 10 ; % etc
```

You can define a predicate like:

```
foo(X + Y = Sum) :-
    between(0, Sum, X),
    between(0, Sum, Y),
    plus(X, Y, Sum).
```

You can try calling `foo(X + Y = 10)`, or `foo(X + 3 = 5)`, or `foo(1 + Y =10)`, or `foo(2 + 2 = 4)`, and so on. Even better, try to use the CLPFD implementation and see how you can use the program.

The most "intuitive" Python solution I could come up with:

```
>>> [(x,y) for x in range(0,11) for y in range(0,11) if x+y == 10]
[(0, 10), (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 1), (10, 0)]
```

As an exercise, try to see how you will wrap this up in a function.

I urge you to try and solve this in C, just to see how much effort it will take you.